# Multiple file preview using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, filereader

I am using the HTML5 API filereader to preview image files. This is the working code I have:

```
function readURL(input) {
if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (e) {
        $('#image_preview')
            .attr('src', e.target.result)
            .width(150)
            .height('auto');
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}
```

And the HTML

```
<img id="image_preview" src="#" alt="" />
```

At the moment this only allows the user to preview one image at a time, how would I change my code to allow multiple image previews?

Answer (score 0):

```
function readURLs(input) {
    if (input.files) {
        for (int i = 0; i < input.files.length; ++i) {
            var file = input.files[i];
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $('#image_preview'+(i+1))
                   .attr('src', e.target.result)
                   .width(150)
                   .height('auto');
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        }
    }
}
```

with HTML

```
<img id="image_preview1" src="#" alt="" />   
<img id="image_preview2" src="#" alt="" />   
<img id="image_preview3" src="#" alt="" />
```